# Need to Link to an Image on another Page already containing multiple images

Tags: hyperlink

**hello** again...

I need to create a link on one page (my home page) that links directly to a image on another page already containing multiple images.  Thought I knew how to do it...by creating an anchor; & my code looks like this:

```
<a href="theOtherPage.html#PHOTO.png">IMAGE SUBJECT</a>
```

but it doesn't work.  Even tried the forward slash after the page id:

```
<a href="theOtherPage.html/#PHOTO.png">IMAGE SUBJECT</a>
```

when the user clicks the link, I want it to go directly to a specific image on a 2nd page...here's the page:

http://www.moonjams.net/events.html

there's 2 images there now, but there will be more.  The home page links need to go directly to different images on that page you see...(which I thought was a simple anchor)...anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

thanx,

**dox**

Answer (score 0):

You need to give images in the listing file ID's, and then you can link them in your main index by doing the hyperlink as shown below.
Here's an example:

File containing images (imgfile.html):

```
<p>THIS IS THE FILE WHERE THE IMAGES ARE</p>
<p>This is a cat <img alt="Cat" id="cat" src="cat.jpg" /></p>
<p>This is a dog <img alt="Dog" id="dog" src="dog.jpg" /></p>
<p>This is a cow <img alt="Cow" id="cow" src="cow.jpg" /></p>
```

File containing links (index.html):

```
<p>THIS IS THE MAIN FILE</p>
<p><a href="imgfile.html#cat"> Cat </a></p>
<p><a href="imgfile.html#dog"> Dog </a></p>
<p><a href="imgfile.html#cow"> Cow </a></p>
```

I tested this, and does exactly what you need.

You can check the live demo on my own website: https://rawstring.com/tests

After I check your website, looks easy.
Change this (line 43/44):

```
<img src="11thANN002.png" width="600" height="750">
<img src="RBTR.jpg" width="526" height="276">
```

To this (line 43/44):

```
<img id="img01" src="11thANN002.png" width="600" height="750">
<img id="img02" src="RBTR.jpg" width="526" height="276">
```

Then link them this way:

```
<p><a href="events7.html#img01"> Image 01 </a></p>
<p><a href="events7.html#img02"> Image 02 </a></p>
```

And just do it for every image you add to the page. That should do it.

Comment: @doxology in case this answer solved your problem, please accept it by clicking the "V" and the up arrow. Thanks